# Get url for aws ecs cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker-compose, amazon-ecs, mern

I’m trying to deploy a docker compose mern stack app with aws ecs.
I finally got the cluster active with 3 services (node backend, react front and mongodb) using the docker compose interface with

```
docker context use myecscontext
docker compose up
```

Now how do I view the front end via a url?
I want to be proficient in deploying websites for freelance work, is this the way it's done?
I noticed there is  a way to define an ip adress in docker-compose.yaml, would that be the way? basically like this:

```
x-aws-loadbalancer:
   IpAddressType: "ipv4"
   VpcId: "vpc-123456"
   LoadBalancerArn: "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-east- 
   1:1234567890:loadbalancer/app/myloadbalancer/123abcd456"
   DNSName: "myloadbalancer-123456.us-east- 
   1.elb.amazonaws.com"
```

where the DNSName is the url?
*edit i found the dns name in load balancer page on aws console but it won't load, this is my docker-compose.ymal maybe something is wrong here

```
 version: "3.7"

 services:
   server:
       build:
       context: ./server
       dockerfile: Dockerfile
     image: anthonyss09/thebikeshop:bike-server
     container_name: myapp-node-server
     logging:
       driver: awslogs
       options:
         awslogs-region: us-east-1
         awslogs-group: bike-server-container
     command: /usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin/nodemon server.js
     volumes:
       - my-data:/user/src/app
     ports:
       - "5000:5000"
     depends_on:
       - mongo
     env_file: ./server/.env
     environment:
       - NODE_ENV=development
     networks:
       - app-network
   mongo:
     image: anthonyss09/thebikeshop:bike-mongo
     volumes:
       - my-data:/data/db
     ports:
       - "27017:27017"
     networks:
       - app-network
   client:
     build:
       context: ./client
       dockerfile: Dockerfile
     image: anthonyss09/thebikeshop:bike-client
     container_name: myapp-react-client
     logging:
       driver: awslogs
       options:
         awslogs-region: us-east-1
         awslogs-group: bike-client-container
     command: npm run build
     volumes:
       - my-data:/user/app
     depends_on:
       - server
     ports:
       - "80:80"
     networks:
       - app-network

 networks:
   app-network:
     driver: bridge

 volumes:
   my-data:
   node_modules:
   web-root:
     driver: local
```

Comment: The `DNSName` of the load balancer is your URL. You do not want to use the IP address because the address of the load balancer can change.

Comment: Thank you, but I don't see the dns when viewing my cluster in aws console. So are the lines of docker-compose.yaml i wrote above neccessary to obtain the dns?

Comment: The DNS name isn't shown on the cluster page, it's shown on the load balancer page (over on the EC2 console). Adding it to the docker-compose file would only make sense if you created the load balancer yourself, manually, and wanted to tell docker to use that load balancer instead of creating one.

Comment: thanks i found it, just have to figure out why it won't load now...  it says it's active and tasks are running

Comment: is their anything you could spot out of placer in my docker-compose.yaml i'll post it in an edit

Comment: What is the error message you get when you try to load the website? Is it a timeout? A 503 error? Be specific. Also, you should check the container logs for any errors or issues.

Comment: that's sort of my problem, i can't find any error messages or logs, it jus eventually hits 'site can't be reached'. I assume you mean the container logs in cloudwatch but they only have up until the latest build from compose up. I'll trouble shoot a few things shortly.